# How can you transfer files from Yammer to Onedrive without doing it one by one?

Tags: microsoft-office, sharepoint

I need to move the files in yammer groups out to onedrive for storage as we are going to stop using yammer.  Is there an efficient way to move the files that are attached to yammer groups to onedrive?

Comment: Yammer stores its files in sharepoint. Have you tried looking for solution how to move sharepoint files to OneDrive?

Comment: According to the thread [Yammer and OneDrive Integration](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/yammer/yammer-and-onedrive-integration/m-p/31674), there is no linkage between a file in your OneDrive (or SharePoint for that matter) and the copy of the file you add to the Yammer files.